# rsync: can rsync adjust to the directory layout insteaed of transferring?

Tags: rsync, mirroring, copy

I have three systems, but only the target and a outdated mirror are on a fast link.

Master_SLOW:
On a super slow link. Contains a updated directory structure and files

OldMirror_FAST:
On a fast link - most files are bit by bit identical to Master_SLOW , but scattered around in a completely different directory structure. Some filenames are outdated (but the content is the same) and some files are missing as well.

What I want to do...
I would like to pull the files from OldMirror_FAST (with the wrong directory layout, but correct files) to get the bulk data quickly.
Afterwards I would like to pull from Master_SLOW to update the directory structure, correct the filenames and download only the missing files.

Can rsync help me do this or am I better off looking at something else?